# Tomcat SSL connector configuration with HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, tls1.2

Hi I have tomcat container configured like this:

```
<Connector 
    port=...
    connectionTimeout=...
    maxThreads=...
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="path to keystore"
    keystorePass="pass"
    truststoreFile="path to truststore"
    truststorePass="pass to truststore"
    keyAlias=...
    clientAuth=...
    sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
```

I have both client and server wars deployed on the same tomcat. So I expecting that while ssl handshake client will receive server certificate from keystore (that configured on connector), and will validate it in front of truststore (that configured on connector).

My client code looks like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

        String requestMessage = "some request";
        try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream())) {
            out.write(requestMessage);
        }
```

The problem is that I am failing with SSLHandshake PKIX exception, which usually happens if I failed validation for some reason (certificate not valid, not trust store not valid or don't have appropriate CA)

After debugged it I see that I have some default ssl context with trust store configured (it is not my trust store).

**My questions:**
 **1.** How can I implement client such way that it will get trust store from the tomcat connector... 
 **2.** Is it java stand art trust store that i see? From where it is getting it?

I can actually set custom **SSLContext** on HTTP**S**UrlConnection like this:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

however I don't want to give the truststore manually, I want to use that one from tomcat connector.

Comment: Keep in mind that the configured keystore is for your SERVER'S SSL certs. Your client code will receive an SSL cert from the server it calls and will validate that cert against your trusted root certs in your CACERTS file (not your keystore). Java gives you a prepopulated CACERTS at \jre\lib\security\cacerts.

Comment: Yes I clearly understand that it will validate server certificate it in front of TRUST store. Just wanted to understand if it possible to change this truststore of java and get it from connector. 

In connector I have keystore (for server certificates) and also truststore configured. 

So what is the purpose of trust store on tomcat connector? Is it there ONLY for mutual authentication?